# Scala Generics: Using recovering actual type to call another generic function

Tags: scala, generics

This might seem like a contrived problem but it's because I've simplified it from a bigger program.

I already have an existing generic method in class Environment:

```
class Environment {
    def obtain[T <: Element](param : Int)(implicit ctag : ClassTag[T]): Array[T] = { ... }
}
```

I also define

```
abstract class Process[T <: Element : ClassTag] { 
    def run(input : Array[T]) : Array[_ <: Element]
}
```

and some concrete classes

```
class Oxidation extends Process[Hydrogen] { ... }
class Reduction extends Process[Water] { ... }
```

Now I would like to have a collection of Process and run each of them in sequence. Here's how I would hope to write it:

```
val myEnv = new Environment
val allProcesses : Seq[Process[_]] = Seq(new Oxidation, new Reduction)
allProcess.map(proc => 
    val material = myEnv.obtain[proc.*SPECIFIC TYPE HERE*](1)
    proc.run(material)
)
```

The reason why I can't supply myEnv into proc (which does compile and execute correctly) is because I am hoping to optimise the program like so:

```
val myEnv = new Environment
val allProcesses : Seq[Process[_]] = Seq(new Oxidation, new Reduction)
allProcess.map(proc => 
    val material = myEnv.obtain[proc.*SPECIFIC TYPE HERE*](1)
    proc.run(material)
    anotherProc.run(material)
    anotherProc2.run(material)
)
```

Any clue? I am open to refactoring most parts of the program, as long as I can dynamically call myEnv.obtain[someVariable] if it's possible at all.

I am using scala 2.10.6. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a ClassTag for the TypeParameter of each individual `Process`.
The `Process` class already requires such a `TypeTag[T]` to be implicitly passed to its constructor, that you may expose:

```
abstract class Process[T <: Element : ClassTag] {
  def ctag: ClassTag[T] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
  def run(input : Array[T]) : Array[_ <: Element] = { ... }
}

val myEnv = new Environment
val allProcesses: Seq[Process[_ <: Element]] = Seq(new Oxidation, new Reduction)

// This functions binds the type parameter of `proc` as `T`, so we can refer to it.
def doRun[T <: Element](proc: Process[T]) = {
  val material = myEnv.obtain[T](1)(proc.ctag)
  proc.run(material)
}
for (process ← allProcesses) yield doRun(process)
```